# Qt ProxyModel performance problems

Tags: qt, c++11, qt5

So I have this Qt application with a `QTreeView` with a custom model (derived from `QAbstractItemModel`) and a custom model proxy for filtering (derived from `QSortFilterProxyModel`). More or less straightforward (somewhat similar to the  [and works fine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html)) and works fine in terms of functionality.

The view shows a two-column tree with key-value pairs. The keys are updated very rarely but the values are updated frequently (a lot of entries with several updates every second each). In the proxy model I overload `filterAcceptsRow` to define visibility based on the **key** column. But every **value** change emits a `dataChanged` signal causing the view to call the proxy (`filterAcceptsRow`) again and that call is somewhat expensive (evaluate a regex on the element and its children). There is some room for optimization in `filterAcceptsRow` by caching all the calculations but it would be preferred to limit the calls to that function. Can it somehow be limited what columns trigger the calls to the proxy?

You have any advise for me?

Edit: Thanks for your input. I wasn't aware of `dynamicSortFilter`. I disabled dynamic sorting and also I connected the `dataChanged`-signal from the model to see if the key-column was changed and called invalidate in that case. That solved it.

Comment: So, to summarize: you don't want every data change to cause the model to be re-filtered? How do you want to trigger filtering then? Anyway, I'd dig into Qt source code, find the spot where `filterAcceptsRow` is actually called, and see if there's anything in the code which might help you.

Comment: I don't think so because `filterAcceptsRow` could be defined arbitrarily, including looking at other rows. I think you'll have change the code of `QSortFilterProxyModel` itself.

Comment: If your code is/can be GPL, or if you have commercial Qt license, then you could simply copy the code of `QSortFilterProxyModel` to your application code, and modify it. Just be sure you understand licensing implications in both cases if you decide to do this. Alternative is to implement equivalent of `QSortFilterProxyModel` yourself from scratch (probably not too big a task).

Comment: @hyde It should be triggered by a change to the key column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code for [`QSortFilterProxyModel`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp#n1159) you'll see that most of the work is only done when `dynamicSortFilter` is enabled. I guess that is the case for your code.

Can you live without it? Maybe call `invalidate()` once every 100 updates or second, depending on which happens first.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved it by emitting `dataChanged` signal from the proxy model itself, not from the main model. Alternatively, you can disable dynamic sort/filtering (`dynamicSortFilter` property) and call it manually when you want to filter or sort.

Also, I'm not sure, but maybe simply specifying the column in `dataChanged` signal will do it for you.